# Is getting the thread ID expensive in terms of performance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching

I need to access the thread ID from threads that I don't control (it's in an asynchronous  callback function, and it get called from a set of different threads).

I'd like to know if accessing the thread ID is expensive in terms of performance ?

I'm planning to use either `boost::this_thread::get_id()` or `GetCurrentThreadId()` from windows.

To clarify, I need to have some local cache array ready for when the data arrives from my callback, and I'm planning, to avoid errors and locking to use a local cache for each thread, and access the right cache using the thread id.
Also because the data that comes is always of a different size, I can not put it in the stack, and I want to avoid creating and deleting heap data all the time.

Comment: I doubt it has effect, but you can simply measure this

Comment: `boot::threads` is just a wrapper for the Win32 threading functions on Windows. There will be little difference between the two, other than portability.

Comment: Wouldn't it be far easier to have a thread-local cache? Let the compiler worry about accessing the right cache for the thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows stores all the thread specific information in the so called [TEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_Environment_Block). In x86 the `fs` register points to the start of this structure, in x64 it is the `gs` register.

In x86 windows the thread id is stored at `FS:[0x24]`, which presumably should be rather cheap to access. Storing the information in thread local storage involves one extra indirection (we get the address of the TLS from the TEB), so it's basically the same as your handrolled private cache - just less work for you.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN (DevDiv#1039430)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-part-2/), prior to VS2015

> this_thread::get_id() was unnecessarily slow

Just how slow they don't say.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using thread local storage?
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html

Comment: that's a good idea. They still don't really mention performances.